# What kind of tag could we use for craft prerequisites?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am struggling with a title much in the same was as I am with the tags for this concept. [I recently asked a questions about forming wire](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-can-i-efficiently-make-the-loops-for-chain-mail-or-small-chain-crafts). I had thought about adding [costumes](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costumes) to the question but decided against it since I was not actually asking about costumes or the armour specifically but one part of the process in it's fabrication.... making/forming wire.

At the time of *this* question the only tags on the one linked above were [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) and [wire](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire). I have a strong need to add a more specific tag for what I was asking in the Main question.

Do we need a tag where the wiki would be "For making materials for use in other crafting projects". Something like [material-fabrication](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-fabrication) which is too long.... This would be a meta tag that would work will with wire. However I could see this overused and ultimately useless

I could be wrong about what I am asking for but I think my question needs another tag.

Comment: Seems like it could do with "technique", for now.

Comment: @CreationEdge I feel silly now. That should have occurred to me already.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think such a tag should be necessary. If a material is a prerequisite for a craft, then it's part of the craft. The craft tag alone should be sufficient.

However, if you're also asking about a specific material you're using within your craft, then include that.

In your example, I would suggest [armor-making](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armor-making) (unless there's another name for that craft) plus [wire](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire), which you've already used. You're asking specifically about wire in the context of armor making.

Another example would be [costume-design](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costume-design) + [styrofoam](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/styrofoam) if you were asking how to combine pieces of styrofoam into the size you need for a cosplay design. In this case, people that make cosplay designs are most likely to have the experience to know the best way to accomplish this task for *your purpose*, and not just in a general way. Likewise, it'll help others with the same question more easily reach the answers.

Comment: Yeah I should just leave it. `technique` fills the gap I was looking for. I am not going to add `armour-making` as that is not _really_ what the question is asking. But something to come out of this is `costume-design` which could be cool.... That makes me wonder about `clothing-design` though.... which _seems_ odd at first glance.

Comment: @Matt I think we'd need some experts to help decide on those tags. `apparel`, `fashion-design`, or ??? I don't know how to name them.